# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError after updating to API 23

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am building an android app and when I was halfway through I updated my SDK version using SDK manager, I also updated Android Studio to 1.3.2. After doing this my app crashes on certain devices, but not all.

The error I am getting is

```
Process: com.pickingo.fe, PID: 11543
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompatApi23$1
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308)
            at com.activeandroid.ReflectionUtils.getModelClasses(ReflectionUtils.java:83)
            at com.activeandroid.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:46)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
            at com.activeandroid.Registry.openDatabase(Registry.java:149)
            at com.activeandroid.Registry.initialize(Registry.java:107)
            at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:8)
            at com.pickingo.fe.Application.onCreate(Application.java:25)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1034)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4605)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1353)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

and this is my Application.java class

```
import android.content.Context;

import com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid;
import com.pickingo.fe.notification.NotificationManager;
import com.pickingo.fe.preference.PreferenceManager;
import com.pickingo.fe.sync.ServerUpdatePusher;
import com.pickingo.fe.test.StoreLogcat;

public class Application extends android.app.Application {


    public static boolean init = true;

    public static final String PF_INIT = "pf_init";


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        new Thread(new StoreLogcat()).start();
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        ActiveAndroid.initialize(context);
        ServerUpdatePusher.init(context);
        NotificationManager.init(context);
        PreferenceManager.init(context);
        //GPSFetcherSingleton.init(context);


        init = false;
        android.preference.PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putBoolean(PF_INIT, false).apply();
    }


}
```

Also this is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.x.y"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    compile project(':lib_MaterialDesign_EditText')
    compile project(':library_Android_Validator')
    compile project(':lib_MaterialDesign')

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-core:0.+'
    compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:0.+'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.+'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Your build.gradle file says you're still targeting SDK 22

Comment: Of course, you haven't included `com.activeandroid.DatabaseHelper.onCreate()` which is where the error is occuring so not sure what that is attempting to do ;)

Comment: @Egor, I tried 23 as well but in vain

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'`, you are saying you always want the latest version of the RecyclerView library. This then pulls in the newest revision (in this case, `23.0.1`), causing your app to use the API 23 specific versions of RecyclerView and its dependencies - namely, `support-v4:23.0.1`, which is where your error is coming from.

You can instead declare a specific version level of `RecyclerView` such as:

```
'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.+'`
```

If you want to stay on the API 22 built dependency, although in many cases, using a dynamic version number at all [is a bad idea](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/09/09/dont-use-dynamic-versions-for-your-dependencies) - instead consider using the exactly `22.2.1` latest version of the API 22 version.

Comment: ianhanniballake you saved my day !! Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Strangest part is that using `compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.0'` on pre-lollipop doesn't throw above exception but does on Lollipop!

Comment: and what to do if i'm using some third party library and that library is using the Api 23 components?

Comment: You should always seek to update to the latest Support Library and compile with the latest SDK. Of course, just because you compile with a new SDK does not mean you need to target it (for example, you could continue to target API 22 but use the 24.1.0 Support Library)

Comment: Will compiling with lets say 23 while target = 21 means that when my app runs on a phone with marshamllow it will work with the new permission model (run time permissions)?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar - you must target API 23 to use runtime permissions (keep in mind that targeting 23 requires compiling with 23 as per [this blog post on SDK versions](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd))

Answer (score 0):

`FingerprintManager` is supported in API 23 and Higher. Your App's minimum SDK support is 15.

If your app is running on the device with Android version older than Marshmallow then you need to use `FingerprintManagerCompat` otherwise you will encounter above exception.