# Error: package com.google.android.gms.appstate does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

Can't compile my android project because of this error.

```
/BaseGameUtils/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper.java
Error:(32, 39) error: package com.google.android.gms.appstate does not exist
Error:(293, 28) error: cannot find symbol variable AppStateManager
Error:(294, 30) error: cannot find symbol variable AppStateManager
Error:Execution failed for task ':BaseGameUtils:compileReleaseJava'.
```

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>       Information:BUILD FAILED

My gradle..

```
apply plugin: 
'android-library' repositories 
{ 
   mavenCentral() 
} 
buildscript 
{ 
  repositories
  {
     mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies
  { 
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
  }
}
dependencies
{ 
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+' 
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+' 
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+' 
} 
android 
{ 
   compileSdkVersion 21 
   buildToolsVersion '21.0.0' 
   defaultConfig 
   { 
      minSdkVersion 14 
      targetSdkVersion 23 
   } 
   productFlavors { } 
}
```

Comment: can you post your gradle file?

Comment: apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see that you have not specified the goggle play services library.

Instead of this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

Try this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
```

Note: You might have a different version so instead of 7.8 enter that.

Comment: But + symbolises new version? I'll try that too.

Comment: + is evil, see this question posted by me and the accepted answer too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32484185/getting-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-after-updating-to-api-23

Comment: What is the latest version? Is it 8.1.0?

Comment: Thanks @Varunkr It helped.

Answer (score 1):

Bump, in my case I was using too high version:

```
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1"
```

I changed it to:

```
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.+"
```

It worked but I have no idea why isn't `appstate` included in versions above 7

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should check that /extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib> is exist.

Secondly you add code in build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+'
```

Comment: Where can i find extras folder?

Comment: Open local.properties and you can see sdk path. it is there.

Comment: i have it. Any other solution? I also added the compile code in build.gradle. Not sure what i'm missing

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the com.google.android.gms.appstate package. you should add this to your app. for that add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+'` to your build.gradle(Module:app).

Comment: Already Added:                                                                             dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}