# 4 Errors - error: package com.google.android.gms.appstate ETC

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, package

I'm fairly new to this and would like it if someone could like really dumb this down for me. I have been receiving these 4 errors constantly and its pretty frustrating.

I'm currently using Android Studio on a mac. These errors pop up when I try to create the build and I've tried searching online for this problem but this is what I found [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33014599/error-package-com-google-android-gms-appstate-does-not-exist) and still did not help.

```
/Users/name/Desktop/test/game/BaseGameUtils/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper.java

Error:(32, 39) error: package com.google.android.gms.appstate does not exist
Error:(293, 28) error: cannot find symbol variable AppStateManager 
Error:(294, 30) error: cannot find symbol variable AppStateManager 
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. Error:Execution failed for task ':BaseGameUtils:compileDebugJava'.
 > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

This doesn't allow me to create any build

> Information:BUILD FAILED

```
 /Users/name/Desktop/test/game/BaseGameUtils/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper.java:32: error: package com.google.android.gms.appstate does not exist
    import com.google.android.gms.appstate.AppStateManager;
                                          ^
    /Users/name/Desktop/test/game/BaseGameUtils/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper.java:293: error: cannot find symbol
                builder.addApi(AppStateManager.API);
                               ^
      symbol:   variable AppStateManager
      location: class GameHelper
    /Users/name/Desktop/test/game/BaseGameUtils/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/GameHelper.java:294: error: cannot find symbol
                builder.addScope(AppStateManager.SCOPE_APP_STATE);
                                 ^
      symbol:   variable AppStateManager
      location: class GameHelper
    Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    3 errors

     FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':BaseGameUtils:compileDebugJava'.
    > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Comment: You have to post the code that generates these errors, and explain what you tried to fix them.

Comment: I've edited the question with more info I'm not sure if this helps much. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that:

1. the package com.google.android.gms.appstate is not found. You haven't linked it to your program.
2. AppStateManager is not recognized, but it is the consequence of the first error.

Comment: How exactly do I link it?

Comment: Normally in your IDE, if you click on your project you can add/link an other project of jar file.