# NoClassDefFoundError: FingerprintManagerCompatApi23 after updating to API 23

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I updated by gradle to API 23 as well as the dependencies but when I tried running my app I get a NoClassDefFoundError:

```
10-11 01:26:30.794 11323-11323/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-11 01:26:30.794 11323-11323/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.aufmschoolbliz.app, PID: 11323
10-11 01:26:30.794 11323-11323/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompatApi23$1
10-11 01:26:30.794 11323-11323/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
10-11 01:26:30.794 11323-11323/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
10-11 01:26:30.794 11323-11323/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.activeandroid.ReflectionUtils.getModelClasses(ReflectionUtils.java:83)
10-11 01:26:30.794 11323-11323/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.activeandroid.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:46)
10-11 01:26:30.794 11323-11323/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
10-11 01:26:30.794 11323-11323/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
10-11 01:26:30.794 11323-11323/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.activeandroid.Registry.openDatabase(Registry.java:149)
10-11 01:26:30.794 11323-11323/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.activeandroid.Registry.initialize(Registry.java:107)
10-11 01:26:30.794 11323-11323/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:8)
10-11 01:26:30.794 11323-11323/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.activeandroid.app.Application.onCreate(Application.java:9)
10-11 01:26:30.794 11323-11323/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.aufmschoolbliz.app.SchoolBliz.onCreate(SchoolBliz.java:42)
10-11 01:26:30.794 11323-11323/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1012)
10-11 01:26:30.794 11323-11323/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4553)
10-11 01:26:30.794 11323-11323/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
10-11 01:26:30.794 11323-11323/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
10-11 01:26:30.794 11323-11323/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-11 01:26:30.794 11323-11323/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-11 01:26:30.794 11323-11323/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
10-11 01:26:30.794 11323-11323/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-11 01:26:30.794 11323-11323/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-11 01:26:30.794 11323-11323/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
10-11 01:26:30.794 11323-11323/com.aufmschoolbliz.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Grade file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 4
        versionName "2.1.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':numberPickerSupport')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
}
```

According to ianhanniballake, https://stackoverflow.com/a/32484445/2450000, it is because of the dependencies but I'm not using dynamic version number.

Answer (score -1):

My dependencies is more clear

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile files('libs/activeandroid-3.0.jar')
```

Done!The following is what I done to solve this.
1. Change all of the AppCompatActivity into Activity.
2.

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
```

Change v7 from 23.1.0 to 21.0.+

3. Change project compiler version from 6.0(API23) to 5.0(API21)

My application run with ActivieAndroid again

Comment: This problem caused by Active Android which is a dead project.

https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/issues/431

Comment: Suggested to use DBFlow or Ollie (by the Active Android author).