# Active android - application crashes

Tags: android, android-studio, noclassdeffounderror, activeandroid

I re installed android studio, and since then I am facing the problem in my logcat :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: loop.org.digitalgreen.loop, PID: 21167
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompatApi23$1
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
at com.activeandroid.ReflectionUtils.getModelClasses(ReflectionUtils.java:83)
at com.activeandroid.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:46)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
at com.activeandroid.Registry.openDatabase(Registry.java:149)
at com.activeandroid.Registry.initialize(Registry.java:107)
at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:8)
at loop.org.digitalgreen.loop.utils.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:41)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1035)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4638)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1378)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

It was working fine previously.

My gradle file looks like :

```
    buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}}apply plugin: 'com.android.application' apply plugin: 'io.fabric'                                android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "A.b.c"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
} } dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile files('libs/activeandroid-3.0.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}

compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'}
```

I also tried active android 3.1 beta gradle link but that is also not working.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: call `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'`

Comment: thats also not working

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the AA_MODELS tag in your manifest, more info here: https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Creating-your-database-model#speeding-up-application-startup

Answer (score 0):

Try to change **libs/activeandroid-3.0.jar** to

`compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'`

Comment: perhaps com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompatApi23$1

Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no definition of the class could be found.

You have to add repositories code above the dependencies in **Build.gradle(app)**

```
 repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}
```

Then call

```
compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32484185/getting-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-after-updating-to-api-23

Comment: Now the problem is with the querying up of database. It is giving error when i am trying to query my db

Comment: @AbhishekLodha uninstall app and run again .then check Sqlite db problem

Comment: @AbhishekLodha Did you fix yet ?

Comment: Yes that was fixed. Thanx.

Comment: But the unique and index constraints on columns is not working.